# Methods for d-dimensional convex hull

Tags: optimization, algorithms, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I'm trying to find an efficient (polynomial time) algorithm that will be able to construct a convex hull out of n-points in d-dimensions. Most algorithms are only suitable for 2 or 3-dimensions (like Graham Scan or Jarvis March). I also looked through https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/pubs/ConvexHullAlgorithm.pdf which seems to apply to many dimensions, but its time complexity is suboptimal. Can anyone suggest a better algorithm to use in this case, or does one simply not exist?

Comment: The widely used Quickhull algorithm was published in 1996 after the paper you've mentioned.  I don't know what the current best asymptotic complexity is or where to find a good implementation.